# How do I convert a byte array to a string?

Tags: c#, winforms, unicode, byte, ascii

I have a byte that is an array of 30 bytes, but when I use [BitConverter.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) it displays the hex string. The byte is
`0x42007200650061006B0069006E00670041007700650073006F006D0065`.
Which is in Unicode as well.

It means B.r.e.a.k.i.n.g.A.w.e.s.o.m.e, but I am not sure how to get it to convert from hex to Unicode to ASCII.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use one of the [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) classes - you will need to know what encoding these bytes are in though.

```
string val = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myByteArray);
```

The values you have displayed look like a Unicode encoding, so `UTF8` or `Unicode` look like good bets.

Comment: @IanLundberg: Note that if you use `Encoding.UTF8` you'll get a string which is twice as long as it should be for your input data. In some output forms you may not *see* that, but every other character will be U+0000.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like that's little-endian UTF-16, so you want [`Encoding.Unicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.unicode.aspx):

```
string text = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes);
```

You shouldn't normally *assume* what the encoding is though - it should be something you know about the data. For other encodings, you'd obviously use different `Encoding` instances, but [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) is the right class for binary representations of text.

EDIT: As noted in comments, you appear to be missing an "00" either from the *start* of your byte array (in which case you need `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode`) or from the *end* (in which case just `Encoding.Unicode` is fine).

(When it comes to the other way round, however, taking arbitrary binary data and representing it as text, you should use hex or base64. That's not the case here, but you ought to be aware of it.)